# Inserting and updating n Rows in Sqlite database fails :(

Tags: java, sqlite

[Click Here For Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Km3C3.jpg)When I am trying to insert 8 rows using for loop the result varies between 2 - 8 rows per execution

Example

in 1st Execution
7 rows inserted instead of 8 into the database

in 2nd Execution
8 rows inserted into the database (which i want in every execution)

in 3rd Execution
3 rows inserted instead of 8 into the database

This is my code

```
try {

    for(int g = 0; g < 8 ; g++)
    {
        sql = String.format("insert into Sorted_Table (marks,category,books,subject,lesson,medium,school_books,questions,standard,image,image1,image2,fimage,exercise,year,status,ans,ans1) select * from Temp where rowid = %d",numbers.get(g));
        pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.executeUpdate();
        sql = String.format("update Sorted_Table SET qno = '%d',attempt = '%d',total = '%d',subqn = '%s' where rowid = (select max(rowid) from Sorted_Table) ",4,1,1,'B');
        pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.executeUpdate();

        sql = String.format("update Sorted_Table SET attempts = '%s',totals = %d where qno = '%d' and subqn = '%s' ",'5',8,4,'B');
        pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.executeUpdate();
    }
}
catch(Exception f)
{
    f.printStackTrace();
}
```

here numbers is an arraylist which contains 8 random numbers.

in 1st query i'm inserting data from table temp to sorted_table

in 2nd query i'm updating the last inserted row

in 3rd query i'm updating the rows using where clause

During execution There are no errors or warnings

*Check the Image for output

Comment: Welcome on SO. Please take a [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to understand how to ask questions on SO. Questions like: Give me the solution to something are not likely to be answered. Please reformate your and describe the problem in more detail.

Comment: Show some example data and the desired result.

Comment: Hello CL,

I have attached the output in the form of image